# How to redirect to a node/add page after clicking on a flag link

Tags: flags

I want to set a flag to link to a node creation page - i.e., when a user clicks on the flag ("Apply for this Job") they should be redirected to a Job Application creation page where they can fill out an application for the job.

So for flag action I selected the "Redirect to URL" action and entered node/add/job-application. But when a user clicks on the flag there's no such redirection, the user is never sent to the node creation page. Am I missing something or just using the wrong method?

Comment: There is an issue about that on [drupal.org](http://drupal.org/node/1503010) for Drupal 6 but it seems that it doesn't work on drupal 7 too. Maybe try to do that with your own module as they said :`hook_flag and $_GET['destination'] = 'your/url'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I myself test this for you, please first install and enable `Rule` and `Rules UI`  ,after it (I suppose you have a flag with 'myflag') .
Go to `dmin/config/workflow/rules`  and `Add new rule` ,set your name and in  **React on event**  in flag group select `A node has been flagged, under "myflag"`  save it ,after it in **Actions** section  choose `Add action` , in **Select the action to add** in `system` group choose **Page redirect** ,after it set your path want to redirect it in **Value**. (is better check **Force redirect**). 
I hope works for you correctly.

Comment: Thanks zhilevan, I got it to work. But there is one more thing I had to do to make it work - I had to make the "Link type" a Normal Link. It seems that it does not work with AJAX.

Comment: I am with you, keep on. please select `javascript` type instead of link type in yourflag settings

Answer (score 0):

If you jobs is too force I suggest you handle your job with jquery and javascript.

something like this

```
$('.flaglinkclass').click(function(){
  document.location.href = "youroptionamlpath";
 });
```

Comment: I'm not much of a programmer, and I was hoping there was a simpler way of doing this. I can use node reference, but the reason I was going with the flag module was that I could use the off switch to disable the Apply link and put in a message like "You have already applied".

Comment: what is your drupal version?

Comment: it is drupal 7 version